# Problem with protocol Microsoft Azure Blob in QGIS

Tags: qgis

I'm trying to upload an image in TIFF format into QGIS using Azure Blob protocol with the name of the BLOB and the storage account key but I have this error:

```
Layer Invalid: provider GDAL You can not open GDAL dataset/vsiaz/cog2/ 3LiES........
Lack AZURE_STORAGE_ACCOUNT + AZURE_STORAGE_ACCESS_KEY
or AZURE_STORAGE_CONNECTION_STRING settings frame layer Provider is invalid 
(Provider: gdal, URL:/vsiaz/cog2/3LiES.............
```

I write the name of the storage account and the key1 of that storage account but I get an error

What could be the problem?

Comment: Please do not use ALLCAPS in question titles; it is interpreted as "shouting" and downvoted for noise abatement.

Comment: Sorry, it's my first forum post. Thanks

Comment: Unlike other issues which are easy spelling fixes, you'll need to [Edit] the Question to retype the title in Title case.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like your storage account and key were not being picked up as environment variables. You can set your storage account and key as environment variables in QGIS by navigating to:

Settings > Options > System > Environment

There is full a step-by-step tutorial here https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fN0nAl7cd-Y